# Google Maps (no plugin) in WP not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

**Problem**

- My company has a web page in WP (Mega Theme) and i manage the blog and other stuff but didn't designed the web
- I don't know how, I touched something in the php code (I'm a kind of rookie, and YES, I know I shouldn't touch) and now the contact map is gone (div class="google-map-container" is there but... empty)
- There's no backup, so I can recover the code

**The code**

Map code is directy written in the PHP (page-contact.php). I let here (pastebin) the PHP code and the HTML that I get when I open the page:

- [Php code](http://pastebin.com/HMzD5Ush)
- [HTML code when i visualize the web](http://pastebin.com/xrGH4mz3)

**Documentation I've read** 
(Low reputation, can't post the links)

API de Google Maps > Web > Maps JavaScript API > Lat/Lng Object Literal

Comment: Have you looked at line 120 of your php code? (This is JavaScript, though) `new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('')`? You should probably specify an element ID. Also, you might want to add the code to your actual post.

Comment: first check your code PHP file there you have leave the comment  like   / <span><?php the_title(); ?></span> on line no  91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per current Google Maps API terms you need to add API key if you want to implement Google Maps in your website.

As of what i can see in your PHP code there is no API key in the api url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false (link taken from your php code)

So you need to generate API key just login to your google account and then visit following link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Use "Get A Key" button to generate api key also mention the website url OR IP address of your website in restrictions as API key works for specified domain,IP OR project only and then use that api key in google map url in your php code which i mentioned above in following format:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap

just replace YOUR_API_KEY with the received API key from Google Maps and your map will start working just like before.

Also in your php file line no 120 and HTML file line no 201 elementid is not mentioned. Change those line with the following one:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
```

Comment: I tried as you said, but doesn't work. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: API keys are normally restricted to use for specific domain name OR IP address OR project so you need to mention website URL at the place where google gave you API key then only it will work. So click on the Name of API key which you generated that will give you option "HTTP referrers" in Key Restrictions select that option and then add the website url in referrers than only it will work. Also i have updated the link google map link in my answer. I found that your HTML file also have the same code so change url at both places that is php and html file.

Comment: If you can share the link of your website i can tell you the exact solution based on the found error.

Comment: In your html file line no. 201 which is: "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(''),mapOptions);" replace it with "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);"       And change the url as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If in case your theme is using the code from php file then make changes in php file as well as mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

The option no 1:

Add this API script into your header or footer

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpuqmav7ndONLkbKvuSo7fUmUX2MW9bcs&callback=initMap"
  async defer></script>
```

From above script you need to replace your google key instead of this

```
  AIzaSyDpuqmav7ndONLkbKvuSo7fUmUX2MW9bcs
```

The option no 2:

For smoothly generate google API key 
Install this plugin :

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/api-key-for-google-maps/screenshots/
```

after genrate api you need to copy and used it into your api script

Thanks

Comment: Tried both. No results. But your help is appreciated.

Comment: can you send me screenshots where would you exactly miss your google map?